# Добавить словарь в список словарей

Tags: python

Есть словарь типа

```
z = { 'a': 1, 's': [{'d': 2, 'f': 3}{'d': 2, 'f': 3}{'d': 2, 'f': 3}]}
```

необходимо добавить ключ\значение из основного словаря в каждый из вложенных не изменяя структуру

```
z = { 'a': 1, 's': [{'d': 2, 'f': 3,'a': 1}{'d': 2, 'f': 3,'a': 1}{'d': 2, 'f': 3,'a': 1}]}
```

Comment: С чем у вас проблема?

Comment: for i in z['a']:
        z['a'][i].append(z['a'])  там проблема с типом данным

Comment: `for d in z['s']: d['a'] = z['a']`

Answer (score 4):

Напишем небольшую функцию для удобства:

```
def update_dicts(dicts, **kwds):
  for d in dicts:
    d.update(**kwds)
```

Далее вызовем её на представленных данных:

```
z = { 'a': 1, 's': [{'d': 2, 'f': 3}, {'d': 2, 'f': 3}, {'d': 2, 'f': 3}]}
update_dicts(z['s'], a=z['a'])
```